# How to get events from a contract deployed on different network? - Web3

Tags: web3js, contract-development, javascript, events, network

I have contract A in *Avalanche FUJI C-chain*.

When I'm on *C-chain* testnet, I can get events from A using getPastEvents() in web3.js, but when I change the testnet (for example, to *Goerli*), I receive an empty array.

How can I get A-events on a *C-chain* while I'm in *Goerli* testnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web3 api doesn't natively support connections to multiple blockchains at once, so you would need to initialize another web3 object using a node url that is on the network you want to query. You can then manage both web3 objects and query both networks.